# Move files with Bat file after so many days

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to setup a bat file that after a certain amount of days (5) moves the files to a different folder.

The folder paths moving from is C:\Mags and is going to C:\Mags\Archives

Thanks,
Liam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an operating system later than XP, you can use the `forfiles` command.

```
@echo off

:: Search in the C:\Mags directory
:: Search for files at least 5 days old
:: Move any file found to C:\Mags\Archive
forfiles /P C:\Mags /C "cmd /c move @file C:\Mags\Archive" /D -5
```